# Place previous and next buttons alongside thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the cycle2 jQuery plugin in my website, it all works but I want to place the prev and next buttons alongside my thumbnails. I didn't want to do absolute positioning as I wanted it to be responsive. Is there a way of constantly aligning the next and prev to the first and last thumbnail?

Here is my code.

Thanks!

```
<div id="main">
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.tile.js"></script>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="slideshow-1">

                    <div id="cycle-1" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-prev="#slideshow-1 .cycle-prev" data-cycle-next="#slideshow-1 .cycle-next" data-cycle-caption="#slideshow-1 .custom-caption" data-cycle-caption-template="Slide {{slideNum}} of {{slideCount}}" data-cycle-fx="tileBlind">
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/slider.jpg" class="img-responsive slideshow-img">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/slider.jpg" class="img-responsive slideshow-img">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/slider.jpg" class="img-responsive slideshow-img">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/slider.jpg" class="img-responsive slideshow-img">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/slider.jpg" class="img-responsive slideshow-img">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/slider.jpg" class="img-responsive slideshow-img">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="slideshow-2">
                    <div id="cycle-2" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-prev="#slideshow-2 .cycle-prev" data-cycle-next="#slideshow-2 .cycle-next" data-cycle-caption="#slideshow-2 .custom-caption" data-cycle-caption-template="Slide {{slideNum}} of {{slideCount}}" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-carousel-visible="5" data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true data-allow-wrap="true">
                        <a href="#" class="cycle-prev">&laquo; prev</a>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" width=100 height=100>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" width=100 height=100>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" width=100 height=100>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" width=100 height=100>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" width=100 height=100>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" width=100 height=100>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="cycle-next">next &raquo;</a>
                    </div> <!-- end of cycle 2 -->
                </div> <!-- end of slideshow 2 -->
            </div> <!-- end of col md 12 -->
        </div> <!-- end of container -->
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
```

Here is how it looks at the moment

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `position: absolute;` can be totally responsive, and I would advise to use this. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: You can set top , left, right and bottom in percentage in `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add float:left and float:right to next and prev:

```
<a href="#" class="cycle-prev" style="float: left;">&laquo; prev</a>
<a href="#" class="cycle-next" style="float: right;">next &raquo;</a>
```

working code here : http://jsfiddle.net/zjvka30q/3/

updated code for improved UI